# Nesting callbacks with setTimeout();

Tags: javascript, callback, settimeout

How could I rewrite this chain of anonymous function definitions into separate functions, so that it is more maintainable and readable? Thanks!

```
function animation(){

    var timeout;
    timeout=timeoutsetTimeout(function(){
        console.log('step1')

        timeout=setTimeout(function(){
            console.log('step2')

            timeout=setTimeout(function(){                                  
                console.log('almost there')

                setTimeout(function(){

                        console.log('grand finale')

                    }, 300);

            }, 1000);


        }, 2000);


    }, 5300);
}
```

Comment: This is off-topic for Stack Overflow. Try http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Look up jquery Promises.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

handily, you can use closure instead of IOC or DI in JS:

```
function animation(){

    var timeout;

    function one(){
        console.log('step1');
        timeout=setTimeout(two, 2000);
    }

    function two(){
        console.log('step2');
        timeout=setTimeout(three, 1000);
    }

    function three(){
        console.log('almost there');
        timeout=setTimeout(four, 300);
    }

    function four(){
        timeout=console.log('grand finale');
    }

   return timeout=setTimeout(one, 5300);

}
```